# Clarification on Immigration Stamping - Flight to UK → Sailing to South Africa → Flight to India

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, gibraltar

I am an Indian Citizen. Planning to travel to Gibraltar using visa for UK with 6 months validity and multiple entry visa.
After reaching Gibraltar since I love sailing in boat planning to travel in a cargo ship as passenger to South Africa. I will also have the South African visa. From there I would travel back to India.

In the above case I would like to clarify the following:

1. Will I be given exit stamp in UK gibraltar?
2. If not whether I can get the UK exit stamp through some UK Embassy since I travel to South Africa in cargo ship.
3. While entering into South Africa is it enough if I get the immigration entry stamp of South Africa. Does it mean it will be automatically informed to UK immigration?

Answer (score 2):

Gibraltar does grant visa-free entry to holders of a valid UK multiple entry visa issued for 6 months or more but it is distinct from the UK as far as visa and entry is concerned. In any case, the UK does not stamp passports on exit. If you are flying from the UK to Gibraltar, your exit will be recorded and that's what the UK authorities will use.

On the other hand, if you would enter from the Schengen area (the land border from Spain), it's important to make sure you get an exit stamp, if necessary by approaching the Spanish border police yourself.

I am not entirely sure of the details of the procedure in Gibraltar but usually a ship's master would provide a list of passengers to the authorities. Exit procedure might not be as streamlined as in an airport, with waiting queues and the like, but if you need a stamp or something, you can simply approach the police/customs at the port.